# "Flag Posts" privilege wiki needs some updates

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, new-users, privileges-page

The flag window screenshot on the "Flag Posts" privilege wiki is outdated now with the recent changes to the flag dialogue. In addition a few of the flag reasons are now outdated and need some editing as well.

[image: Current Window]

Could a friendly neighborhood 20K+ please update it with an updated screenshot and update the flag reasons list?

Comment: Actually, you only need 1,000 reputation on Meta to edit the privilege wikis. :)

Comment: @animuson Really? The [20k privilege wiki](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/trusted-user) lists it as a 20k privilege. Perhaps another update is in order?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have taken new screenshot and [added it in](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/66246/15). I am not confident in my meta knowledge, so I will leave the harder job of editing the text to someone else.

Comment: I've edited the text for you.

Comment: @michaelb958: You linked to the wrong question for the VLQ flag.

Comment: That's what happens when your text box malfunctions and you press Backspace one too many times.